# How to install Firmware 1.10E on an EV3 home/retail edition brick

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, compatibility

If and how can you install firmware 1.10E on an EV3 brick from an home/retail edition set (instead of an education set)? Updates 1.0E9 are only recognized from the Mindstorm software, also with Education Mindstorm software version.

I am very interested to build projects with makecode.mindstorms.com.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### New answer (2020)

The V1.10E firmware is installed using the [EV3 Device Manager](https://ev3manager.education.lego.com/) web page. The instructions are not entirely clear, but if you visit the web page with Chrome (recommended), Safari, Edge, or Internet Explorer, click the *Available Bricks (0)* button and wait a very long time, it will eventually pop up a dialog asking to download and install an *EV3 Device Manager* program to your computer. The EV3 Connection Manager program runs in the background on your computer and communicates with the EV3 Connection Manager web page in the browser. After installing the separate background program, the web page will be able to connect to your EV3. Then you can use it to update the firmware. It does not appear that this method gives you the option of selecting which firmware file to use.

#### Old answer - for retired EV3 Lab software

You can get the 1.10E firmware from the LEGO Education website. Currently, this can be done by clicking the *Download Firmware* button at the bottom of [this page](https://education.lego.com/en-gb/product-resources/mindstorms-ev3/downloads/firmware-update).

In the EV3 programming software, make sure you have a project open (e.g. create a new empty project), then click *Tools > Update Firmware*.

Click the *Show Details* button.

[image: Firmware update dialog]

Then click *Browse* and select the firmware file that you downloaded.

[image]

Make sure your EV3 is connected via USB and powered on, then click *Update Firmware*.

Comment: For some people, however, the new version does not show up in the EV3 software, and I'm one of them. But I managed to find another way to download it.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but the link for downloading the firmware is no longer on the webpage referenced. I too would like to try makecode.mindstorms.com but appear to be unable to do so without firmware version 1.10E. That firmware version does not appear on the Lego website (https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads). It only has version 1.09H. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have updated the answer.

Comment: The Device Manager page is _Forbidden (403)_

Comment: As of Dec 29, 2022 there is a link to download 1.10E here: https://education.lego.com/en-gb/product-resources/mindstorms-ev3/downloads/firmware-update

Answer (score 5):

For anyone searching in 2021 and looking for a tutorial, I finally found an option that works. Lego's browser based EV3 Device manager will NOT work, nor will the 1.5 version of EV3Lab classroom/home edition software.

I wrote a tutorial in a reddit thread [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/mindstorms/comments/pcsacu/how_to_install_and_update_firmware_110e_on_an_ev3/), and have highlights posted below.

1. This has only been verified on a windows 10 computer. It should work on any 7,8,10 windows PC, and theoretically on an intel based Mac; I am unsure on an m1.
2. Download and install the 1.4.5 Lego EV3 lab software from this link [here](https://education.lego.com/nl-nl/downloads/retiredproducts/mindstorms-ev3-lab/software). This is a retired version of the software that still includes the "tools" file menu to allow for manual updates of the firmware.
3. Download the 1.10E firmware [here](https://education.lego.com/en-gb/product-resources/mindstorms-ev3/downloads/firmware-update)
4. Power on and plug in your EV3 to your windows computer.
5. Open "Tools > Firmware Update"
6. In the popup, "Show Details"
7. "Browse" and select the 1.10E.bin file.
8. Click Update Firmware.
9. Success!

As a robotics educator, Lego really does not need to make it this difficult. If for whatever reason the below links break, the reddit thread I posted has links to my google drive where I have stored the original 1.10E firmware and installers.

Answer (score 2):

The web-based EV3 manager will not let you upload an 'E' (education) firmware in a Home edition brick. For some reason the latest education version is 1.10E while the home version is stuck to 1.09H.

But you can use the EV3 software to point to a specific file to upload. Version 1.10E is available here: https://education.lego.com/en-gb/product-resources/mindstorms-ev3/downloads/firmware-update (link at the bottom of the page).

If you don't have it already, install the EV3 software available here: https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads

Launch the EV3 software, select the menu Tools -> Firmware upgrade, then click "Show details". Here you can select a firmware file. Point to the 1.10E firmware that you just downloaded and click 'update'.

Note that I had to shudown and restart the brick once in order to see the EV3 drive on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

- Official LEGO page [here](https://education.lego.com/en-gb/product-resources/mindstorms-ev3/downloads/firmware-update) (plus the firmware file)
- Very good Reddit [tutorial](https://www.reddit.com/r/mindstorms/comments/pcsacu/how_to_install_and_update_firmware_110e_on_an_ev3/)
- Lots of details [here](https://www.brickobotik.de/lego-mindstorms-ev3-die-bisherigen-firmware-versionen/) (in German)